# How to do integrals involving Gauss function and cosine function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I calculate the integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{0.01}}\cos(bx)dx$$
I can not find in the references. Excuse my bad English.

Comment: You could expand the cosine in a Taylor series around $x=a$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

$$
\cos(bx)=\frac12\left(\mathrm e^{\mathrm ibx}+\mathrm e^{-\mathrm ibx}\right)\;,
$$

the integrand becomes the sum of two Gaussians with complex exponents, whose integrals can be evaluated [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory#Integrals_with_a_complex_argument_of_the_exponent).

Answer (score 1):

A reference is Rudin, Principles of mathematical analysis, Example 9.43. Here the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos(xt)\,dx 
$$
is calculated using the theory of ordinary differential equations.
The integral is
$$
\sqrt{\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{4} \right).
$$
(Hint) In your integral after introducing new variable you should calculate 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2}\cos(cz)\,dz
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2}\sin(cz)\,dz.
$$