# Solving $n \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{e^{(itY_j)}}-e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\right|^2}\psi(t)dt$

Tags: integration, summation, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals, absolute-value

I have to solve 
$$
n \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{e^{(itY_j)}}-e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\right|^2}\psi(t)dt
$$
where $\psi(t)=(2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}$ is the density function of the standard normal distribution.

I tried to do it like this:

$$
T_n= n \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\left|\hat{\varphi_n}(t)-e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\right|^2}\psi(t)dt\\
   = n \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{e^{(itY_j)}}-e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\right|^2}\psi(t)dt\\
   = n \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{\cos{(tY_j)}}+i\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{\sin{(tY_j)}}-e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\right|^2}\psi(t)dt\\
   = n \int_{\mathbb{R}}{\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{\cos{(tY_j)}}-e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n{\sin{(tY_j)}}\right)^2\right]}\psi(t)dt\\
   = n \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Bigg[\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^n{\sum_{k=1}^n{\cos{(tY_j)}\cos{tY_k}}}-2\cdot\sum_{j=1}^n{\cos{(tY_j)}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}+e^{-t^2}\\
\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^n{\sum_{k=1}^n{\sin{(tY_j)}\sin{(tY_k)}}}\Bigg]\psi(t)dt\\
   = n \int_{\mathbb{R}}\Bigg[\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j,k=1}^n{\cos{(t(Y_j-Y_k))}}-2\cdot\sum_{j=1}^n{\cos{(tY_j)}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}+e^{-t^2}\Bigg]\psi(t)dt\\
   =  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j,k=1}^n{\int_{\mathbb{R}}{(2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cos{(t(Y_j-Y_k))}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}}dt}-2\sum_{j=1}^n{\int_{\mathbb{R}}{(2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cos{(tY_j)}e^{-t^2}}dt}\\
\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad+n\int_{\mathbb{R}}{(2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{3}{2}t^2}}dt\\
$$

I dont know how to solve the integrals to reach the expected form
$$
T_n= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j,k=1}^n{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left|Y_j-Y_k\right|^2}}-2^{\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{j=1}^n{e^{-\frac{1}{4}\left|Y_j\right|^2}}+n3^{-\frac{1}{2}}
$$

Comment: Despite all the other stuff, your problem boils down to evaluating a few Gaussian integrals. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/216966/137524) for how to deal with the cosine case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally solved it.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'd encourage submitting that work as answer to this question. That'll give you some practice with MathJax, as well as an opportunity to get some rep and feedback.